# Resharper marker bar and Productivity Power Tools scrollbar mismatch

Tags: visual-studio, scrollbar, resharper, productivity-power-tools

Resharper and Productivity Power Tools both provide a "scrollbar" with colored indicators of different problem areas in the code. But they do not match. Example screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ralkJ.jpg

In the example, I would expect the white line indicator to match the red problem indicators. Is there any way I can make these two bars match locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two scrollbars were implemented very differently (by different teams), and have some different padding at the tops and bottoms, etc.  As such, I've found that they never match.  Unfortunately, there is no way to adjust or influence how these tools work.

I've personally just started turning off the scrollbar from the Productivity Power Tools (since you can selectively disable features), as the two mismatched sets with mostly duplicated functionality just wastes space.

Comment: How unfortunate... I think I'm keeping both bars because I like the PPT bar's current line indicator, changed lines indicator, and the usages indicator (when held over a variable/field it will indicate locations of usages).

Comment: Where do you turn these on and off? I just end up with the ReSharper toolbar but I would like to choose.